# Retornar um in_array() true dentro de um resultado SQL

Tags: php, mysql

possuo uma função dentro da classe `UsuarioVisitas`:

```
// Retorna o array com os mais visitados
public function CS_GetMaisVisitados($sql_aux)
{
    global $objConexao;

    $strSql =  "SELECT cod_usuario, SUM(count_view) AS total_visitas 
                FROM usuario_visitas
                $sql_aux";  

    $vetDados = $objConexao->query($strSql)->fetchAll();
    return $vetDados;
}
```

Chamo a função em outra página:

```
$dados_top_visitas = UsuarioVisitas::CS_GetMaisVisitados("GROUP BY cod_usuario ORDER BY total_visitas DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Dessa forma eu quero que ele me traga os 10 usuários mais visitados ordenados descendentemente. É o que está acontecendo. Todavia, meu problema é verificar se certo código de usuário se encontra no resultado. Tentei dessa forma:

```
var_dump(in_array(1182652232, $dados_top_visitas));
```

Mas, neste caso está me retornando `false`, sendo que deveria ser `true` pois o código `1182652232` se encontra entre os 10 resultados da query.

Onde estou errando na lógica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que você deva utilizar o `array_column`

```
var_dump(in_array(1182652232, array_column($dados_top_visitas, 'cod_usuario')));
```

[Teste isto.](https://3v4l.org/muG72)

---

O `in_array` apenas verifica valores que estão na array, mas não nas array dentro de array, portanto:

```
$dados_top_visitas = [
    [
        'cod_usuario' => 2,
        'total_visitas' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'cod_usuario' => 3,
        'total_visitas' => 1,
    ]
];
```

Se fizer um `in_array(2, $dados_top_visitas)`, será `false`.

Usando o `array_column` ele irá criar uma outra array, porém listando todos os `cod_usuario`, assim isso passaria a ser:

```
[2, 3]
```

Isso funcionará, porque ele conseguirá encontrar o `3`, assim como o `2`.

Comment: Perfeito @Inkeliz funcionou exatamente como eu queria. Obrigado por hora!